# Getting icon from resources package (Java)

Tags: java, icons, classloader

I'm trying to make a java program and have an application icon that is resources/Icon.png. My code at the moment is

```
ClassLoader cldr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
URL url = cldr.getResource( "//resources//Icon.png" );
Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image img = kit.createImage(url);
this.setIconImage( img );
```

However I'm getting

> Uncaught error fetching image: java.lang.NullPointerException

Am I referencing the location of the icon correctly? resources is a package in the program.

Comment: I thought that was how you did file locations in java. Single slashes do not work either.

Comment: When using the ClassLoader to load a resource, the path must not start by a slash. It should be `resources/Icon.png`.

Comment: From the [method's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-): "The name of a resource is a '/'-separated path name that identifies the resource." And you are referencing it correctly, iff the resources folder is put into the binary output (or into the JAR file).

Comment: Please add the solution as an answer. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the ClassLoader to load a resource, the path must be a slash-separed path, not starting with a slash:

```
resources/Icon.png
```

If using the class directly (`SomeClass.class.getResource(...)`), then it can start with a slash to look for the resource by starting at the root of the classpath, or it can not start with a slash to look for the resource by starting at the same package as the class.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this will fix it, but change your code so you're using a File and BufferedImage. Let me know if it doesn't.

Edit: Didn't see the bottom. Instead of URL, use a File.

Comment: No! Resource loading should never be done with `File`. Using a `ClassLoader` is the correct way.

Comment: Why not, I was actually taught the opposite.

Comment: And what about resources that are inside a JAR?